# When I use UDF to operate a columns, It have a problem

Tags: pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

When I used UDF to process a Column, I am not sure is the UDF process the element one by one from this column? If so, I cannot understand why there is a problem.

```
import pyspark.sql.types as typ
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
def parse_model(v):
    return v.split(' ')
Parse_model=pandas_udf(parse_model,typ.ArrayType(typ.StringType(),True))
sample_data_df.withColumn('Models',Parse_model('Model')).show(
```

It should be 
     string 
in the column not the series.

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scalar Pandas user-defined function takes `pandas.Series` and returns the result as a `pandas.Series`.

As v is of type Series, you are getting the error. updating the udf like below will fix the issue.

```
def parse_model(v): 
   return pd.Series([v[0].split(' ')])
```

Comment: Thanks! It solve the problem. But don't you think the pandas_udf is more complicated since it involves two-step of conversion between the object and Pd.series?